# Delete a list view Row Titanium

Tags: listview, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

I want to delete a row in list view.
When user clicks a row  I want to open a Dialog showing the message that 'sure you want to delete'.
When user clicks ok then the Row should be deleted.

Comment: If Swanand answered your question correctly, make sure you click the check mark beside his answer! That'll make it more likely that people will answer your questions in the future. Read here for more info! http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
listView.addEventListener('itemclick', function(e){ 
    var section = e.section;
    var itenIndex = e.itemIndex;
    var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
        title : 'Do you want to delete the row?',
        buttonNames : ['Yes','No']
    });
    dialog.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        if(e.index == 0){
            section.deleteItemsAt(itenIndex,1);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
});
```

Comment: Thanx @Swanand ... but i m using list view , not table view .

Comment: @PappuAashiq I have changed the code, now its working fine :)